# Select all elements that are not a descendant of a specified element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Using a jQuery selector, is it possible to select all elements that are not a descendant of the elements from another selector.

For example, I would like to select all the `a` tags that are **not** a descendant of a `th` tag.  The only way I can see to do it right now is as follows:

```
$('a').filter(function () {
   return $(this).closest('th').size() == 0
})
```

Comment: Do you mean sibling or descendant? Your code suggests the latter

Comment: As @lonesomeday implies: **`a` elements *cannot be* siblings of a `th` element**. Could you post the html you're working with?

Comment: It is not valid HTML to have an `a` tag being a sibling of a `th` tag

Comment: @lonesomeday, @David Thomas, @Petah: I did mean descendant, not sibling.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you are looking for descendants (since having a `a` element as a sibling to `th` elements is not valid HTML) you can use the `:not` pseudo-selector to do this:

```
$('a:not(th a)');
```

This should be pretty fast in modern browsers using `document.querySelectorAll`, but might be slower than the original for older versions of IE.

See a simple demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/JR5sP/

Comment: Why I thought the `:not` selector wouldn't do this is beyond me but thanks for the answer.  The demo was great as well.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you do want to do as your question asks (regardless of the invalid HTML fact) and filter out elements with a specific sibling,

You can do this:

```
$('a').filter(function() {
    return $(this).siblings('b').length == 0;
}).css('color', 'orange');
```

HTML:

```
<div>
    <b>Hello there</b>
    <a>Don't select me!</a>
</div>

<div>
    <a>Select me!</a>
    <a>Select me too!</a>
</div>
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/JR5sP/1/