# CSS select all 'code' element that are not a direct descendant of 'pre' tag

Tags: css

I'm trying to select all `code` elements except the one that's a descendant of the `pre` element using a `:not(~)` selector. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4910489/select-all-elements-that-are-not-a-descendant-of-a-specified-element) has a very similar answer but I'm having a hard time figuring out my problem.

```
<body>
<div><code>Div Code</code></div> 
<pre><code>Pre Code</code></pre> <!-- Exclude only this -->
<Code>Body Code</Code>
</body>
```

This selector using `:not(~)` doesn't seem to work.

```
code:not(pre code) {
  color:red;
}
```

The `code` selector selects all three, and `pre code` selects only the 2nd one, so shouldn't joining them using `:not` produce all three except the 2nd one?

What could be wrong here?

I could use a selector other than the `:not(~)` but it fits the best for my use-case since `code` element can be nested in other elements and I want to exclude only the descendants of `pre`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23853931/how-can-i-style-code-only-if-its-parent-is-not-pre

Answer (score 2):

If your `<code>` is always a direct descendant of `<pre>`, you can use the direct descendant combinator to target it:

```css
:not(pre) > code {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div><code>Div Code</code></div> 
  <pre><code>Pre Code</code></pre> <!-- Exclude only this -->
  <Code>Body Code</Code>
</body>
```

Note: if you removed the `>`, intuitively, sure, it should work, but since it can target any ancestor, such as `<body>`, it'll match because `body:not(pre)` is true.

Answer (score -1):

You can't do that. `:not()` works only for the tag itself, not parent tags that wrap it.

What you can do, is add a class to `<code>` like this: `<code class="notpre"></code>` and add a css rule like this:

```
code.notpre {
  color:red;
}
```

[You can read more about `:not()` pseudo-class here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not).

---

Edit 1: You can do this that way too, but it's not recommended because it's too "wide" and can affect some unwanted `<code>` tags. I'd recommend using class names like in the first solution I mentioned.

```css
code {
  color:red;
}
pre code {
  color:initial;
}
```

```html
<div><code>Div Code</code></div> 
<pre><code>Pre Code</code></pre> <!-- Exclude only this -->
<Code>Body Code</Code>
```